# fb:loginbutton icon missing in https:// page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

Missing fb:loginbutton icon in my login page. I've discovered that they all show with http:// but as soon as the site is in https:// all but the ones mentioned disappear. What needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like the image source is `http` and will be blocked by most browsers when in `https` as generally you wouldn't deliver unsecure items over secure channel. Not familiar with the `fb` code, but usually there is a way to specify the protocol.

Comment: Fb:loginbutton is being appeared in ie only when show all content is set